# jQuery select2 get value of select tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Hello friends this is my code:

```
<select id='first'>
  <option value='1'> First  </option>
  <option value='2'> Second </option>
  <option value='3'> Three  </option>
</select>
```

This is my select2 code:

```
$("#first").select2();
```

Below is code for getting selected value.

```
$("#first").select2('val'); // It returns first,second,three.
```

This is return a text like `first,second,three` and I want to get `1,2,3`.
Means I need the value of select box, not text.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? It would be very useful.

Comment: question is not clear. exactly what do u want?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

```
$("#first").val(); // this will give you value of selected element. i.e. 1,2,3.
```

Comment: $("#first").val(); //it return 1,2,3
OR
$("#first").select2('val'); // it return first,second,three

Comment: $("#first").val(); will return 1,2,3 (which ever is selected) and can you post the code in function select2() for more details.

Comment: for an select called by id name instead of class name, use: $(".first").val()

Comment: @RuiMartins wrong. ID's are called with "#" and classes are called with ".", so to call by ID, you'd use $("#first").val() and for CLASS you'd use $(".first").val()

Answer (score 68):

To get Select element you can use `$('#first').val();`

To get the text of selected value - `$('#first :selected').text();`

Can you please post your `select2()` function code

Comment: $("#first").val(); //it return 1,2,3
OR
$("#first").select2('val'); // it return first,second,three

Comment: Am not sure, I did understand your question.

Comment: when i used select2 plugin then i get value using $("#first").val(). it's not return anything it return blank.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle exmaple with your plugin?

Comment: I had to use `$('#first :selected').text();` the other option was returning all possible options.

Comment: $input.find(':selected').text() returns empty string

Answer (score 43):

`$("#first").select2('data')` will return all data as map

Comment: Very useful if you have extra properties on the select2 objects

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 16):

**If you are using ajax**, you may want to get **updated value** of select right after the selection.

```
//Part 1

$(".element").select2(/*Your code*/)    

//Part 2 - continued 

$(".element").on("select2:select", function (e) { 
  var select_val = $(e.currentTarget).val();
  console.log(select_val)
});
```

Credits: Steven-Johnston

Comment: Hi, may i know where is `currentTarget` comes from? none of your ID/name example is related to the Question. So I cannot relate anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much my lord :p Happy Coding

Answer (score 9):

This solution allows you to forget select element. Helpful when you do not have an id on select elements.

```
$("#first").select2()
.on("select2:select", function (e) {
    var selected_element = $(e.currentTarget);
    var select_val = selected_element.val();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer is :

```
$('#first').select2().val()
```

and you can write by this way also:

```
 $('#first').val()
```

Answer (score 5):

Above solutions did not work for me with latest select2 (4.0.13)

With jQuery you can use this solution to retrieve value according to documentation: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections

```
$('#first').find(':selected').val();
```

Comment: It returns only first value of all selected value

Comment: use `$('#first').find(':selected').text();` for the text

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
$('#input_id :selected').val(); //for getting value from selected option
$('#input_id :selected').text(); //for getting text from selected option
```

Comment: @RenishKhunt the answers here are not only for you (person asking the question), but also for other people seeing this page. And the more different solutions are submitted here, the better choice has everyone else, again: not just you :)

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry. Thanks, @infografnet and Thank you so much Fahmi Imanudin for posting an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".element").select2(/*Your code*/)
.on('change', function (e) {
     var getID = $(this).select2('data');
     alert(getID[0]['id']); // That's the selected ID :)
});
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28310557)

Answer (score 2):

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Jaf/).
Basically, you want to get the `value`s of your `option`-tags, but you always try to get the value of your `select`-node with `$("#first").val()`.

So we have to select the option-tags and we will utilize jQuerys selectors:

```
$("#first option").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

`$("#first option")` selects every `option` which is a child of the element with the id `first`.

Comment: $("#first").val(); //it return 1,2,3
OR
$("#first").select2('val'); // it return first,second,three

Comment: Seems like i got your question wrong, then please clarify exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: when i used select2 plugin then i get value using $("#first").val(). it's not return anything it return blank.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3Jaf/1/). Works perfectly well for me. (I added select2.js under the external resources, though i cannot tell why the boxes look ugly).

Comment: the key was that you said that we want to get value of option tags!

Answer (score 0):

Other answers wasn't working for me so i developed solution:

I created option with class=**"option-item"** for easy targeting

**HTML :**

```
<select id="select-test">
<option value="5-val" id="first-id" class="option-item"> First option </option>
</select>
```

Then for every selected option i added **display none** property

**CSS:**

```
option:checked {
   display: none;
}
```

Now we can add **change** to our SelectBox to find our selected option with display none property by simple **:hidden** attribute

**JQuery:**

```
$('#select-test').change(function(){
//value 
    $('#select-test').find('.option-item:hidden').val();
//id
    $('#select-test').find('.option-item:hidden').attr('id');
//text
    $('#select-test').find('.option-item:hidden').text();
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Friiz/2dk4003j/10/

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
var my_veriable = $('#your_select2_id').select2().val();
var my_last_veriable = my_veriable.toString();
```