# cancel change event for a Dropdown without confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want cancel change event when selected item compare with another select list value.
I have 2 selectlist.I want when #SecondUnit_Id changed execute below function but does not work.

```js
var preval=$('#SecondUnit_Id').val();

$('#SecondUnit_Id').change(function(){
  
  if($(this).val()==$('#UnitList_Id').val())
    {
       msgbox("error","Duplicate");
       $(this).val(preval);
       return false;
    
    }
    
    preval=$(this).val();
  
  });
```

But Does Not Work below code:

```js
$(this).val(preval)
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: Try:  `$("#SecondUnit_Id").val($("#SecondUnit_Id option[selected]").val());`

Comment: Dose not work,It changed and no prevent ,In the other hand first changed then check the condition

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8suc4jhz/

Comment: @MohsenZahedi : I already made a working jsfiddle for you. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Its Working For me

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/erq64Lzb/)**

```
<select id="UnitList_Id">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>


<select id="SecondUnit_Id">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>

var preval=$('#SecondUnit_Id').val();
alert(preval)
$('#SecondUnit_Id').change(function(){
  //alert($('#UnitList_Id').val())
  if($(this).val() === $('#UnitList_Id').val())
    {
       alert("error Duplicate");
       $(this).val(preval);
       return false;

    }

    preval=$(this).val();

  });
```

The problem is in your msgbox pluggin . Use the related library properly.

Comment: First item changed then Check Condition.

Comment: Yeah,Your Code is right but It work for a select ,I have select2.

Comment: @MohsenZahedi : that you should have told earlier . Are you using multiselect select2

Comment: Yes,I use multiselect select2.

Comment: Then you must be getting values like val1, val2 ,val3 . you can put all selected values in array and then check using `jQuery.inArray`  if value is selected. I hope this helped you

Comment: I try it,Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @MohsenZahedi : this would help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908273/jquery-select2-get-value-of-select-tag