# Selecting multiple values in Select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 jquery plugin to select mulitple values from dropdown. I have used following code :

```
 <select id="countries" name="countries[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
 </select>
```

Now I couldnot find which property I should use to get the list of selected values

Comment: show your javascript code of select2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery select2 get value of select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908273/jquery-select2-get-value-of-select-tag)

Answer (score 0):

This will give selected value :

```
$("#countries").val();
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help.

```
var value = $('#countries').val();
```

you can check it or join it.

```
alert(value.join(' ,'));
```