# Where is ID saved in django ModelAdmin autocomplete_fields?

Tags: django, django-2.2

I am rewriting some administration interface to django 2.2, currently using django *autocomplete_fields* admin feature. Simply said I have *ModelAdmin* object `OrderAdmin`, which has nested *TabularInline* `ProductAdmin`: variable-length table of products which might be added to order. Each of these `ProductAdmin` holders just contains ForeignKey to actual product class, with some other attributes.

Now I wonder: where does django store id - ForeignKey - of item selected with autocomplete field? It doesn't mark OPTION in selectbox as *selected*, and although there is suspicious hidden input field with *#cashregisterproduct_set-0-id* on page, it doesn't have any value. Or is there some special way how to access it? I was thinking about adding id to `__str__` method of model and parsing, but thats just ugly.

Thanks for tip.

EDIT: to make it 100% clear, **where from does django get ForeignKey of object selected through autoselect_field**, **when creating new object from ModelAdmin**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got misguided thinking that this is managed by django. Selected data might be accessed by using *select2* framework:

```
selected_value = $('.myselectbox').select2().val();
```

related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451658/16268461

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.